# Column is not filling missing value with this groupby transform

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to fill missing value based on `location` and taking **mode** of the column `balcony` in that location.

```
column_balcony = train.groupby('location')['balcony'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode()))
column_balcony = column_balcony.fillna(column_balcony.mode())
train['balcony'] = column_balcony
```

I expect the output to be `train['balcony'].isna().sum()` to be `0`
but its still showing same missing value `609` in `train['balcony']`

Comment: How working if change `.mode()` to `.mode().iat[0]` for both?

Comment: If still not working, what return `column_balcony.isna().sum()` ?

Comment: `column_balcony.isna().sum()` return 609

Comment: @jezrael I am getting `IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0` if i put `.mode().iat[0]` both the places